# How can I disable the error page with flutter go router and have a snackbar instead?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

With flutter go router is it possible to disable the error page? Because I want the error to show in a snackbar instead. I tried doing it in the redirect but the error in the redirect seems empty when for example you route to a page that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch block.

`try { // your code... } catch(e) { final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text('Error ${e}'),);}`

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related to flutter go router? Are you familiar with the package?

Answer (score 0):

Set a `MyErrorPageScreen` Widget and then inside MaterialApp.router -> routerConfig, set

```
     errorBuilder: (context, state) => MyErrorPageScreen()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show a snackbar after you return a page.

This can be achieved by returning the homepage (or whatever page you want to return when a route wasn't matched) and show a snackbar after it has been built ~ If you just show the snackbar and return the page, it will call the `ScaffoldMessenger` during the build step of the page and your app will crash.

If you schedule the snackbar with `SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback` you are displaying the snackbar right after the build step of the page has completed, and the page is ready to do a state update (which `showSnackBar` does).

```dart
errorBuilder: (context, state) {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        'That page does not seem real...',
      ),
    ));
  });
  return const HomePage();
},
```

Comment: But what if I don't want it to go to the home page. What if I don't want it to change page at all and just stay on the current page?

Comment: I think best practice would be to return a page. E.g.: what if your app opens on a page that does not exist? You could return at least an error- (or home-) page so the user has at least one point of entry.
Otherwise you could get the current page from the router state with `GoRouterState.of(context)` and return that one if it exists.